# How can i add new action for selected users

Tags: hooks

[image]

I would like to add a new action within the With selection field and i don't know how to alter that data, i have tried with hooks but i can't find something that's working. If you ever done something similar can you please tell me the steps i need to make for creating another action?

Comment: You'll  need to wait for the VBO port or do custom development, see here http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/154292/how-do-i-bulk-edit-fields-or-taxonomy-of-nodes-in-drupal-8